# Continue loop after Exception?

Tags: c#

I've a foreach that upload some items, now happen in some situations that this items are a duplicate, so I get the message

> constraint failed

'cause I've duplicated key, the problem's that I need to continue the foreach but the exception of course, cause the exit from the loop. A practice example:

```
try
{
   foreach(item in list)
   {
     //code that add item to table 
   }
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Situation:

1. Running the loop (list count = 20)
2. Adding item 1, got error 'cause already added
3. fall in exception

How can I go again in the foreach only if there is a constraint exception?

Comment: The exception handler (try/catch) has to be inside the foreach loop to be able to continue.

Comment: @jdweng uhm but if I need to catch other exception externally?

Comment: The have two exception handles.  No reason you can't have nested exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the exception as indicator if the key is already added - that is very slow!... Check it programatically instead (for instance by: `Dictionary.ContainsKey(key)`).

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code and put `try-catch` inside `for` loop:

```
foreach(item in list)
{
    try
    {
         //code that add item to table 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But it is not good idea to check duplicates by exceptions catching.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch exception and in this block process actions to remove duplicate key, 
then go to **finally** block.